# How are composite ids working in Loopback?

Tags: mongodb, loopback

I am trying to implement composite ids with `Loopback 3.0.0` using `MongoDB`. each pair of `product_id/keyword` should be unique...

I check the official documentation:

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Model-definition-JSON-file.html#data-mapping-properties

Here my model:

```
{
  "name": "comparative",
  "plural": "comparative",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
     "validateUpsert": true
   },
  "properties": {
    "product_id": {
      "id": true,
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "keyword": {
      "id": true,
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {}
}
```

Although, all my attempts to make composite ids of product_id/keyword failed.

When I POST:

```
// 1st POST Success.
{
  "product_id": "string",
  "keyword": "string"
}
// 2nd POST Success.
{
  "product_id": "string1",
  "keyword": "string"
}
// 3rd POST FAILED -> I want it to success
{
  "product_id": "string",
  "keyword": "string1"
}
```

Any ideas?

Even after that, I need to keep an auto-generated MongoDB `id` just to keep track of the objects.

I tried with "idInjection", not working along with composite ids... (not generating anything...)
If I add another field "id" with generated set to true, composite ids doesn't work at all (contrary as before where it worked partially)

Thank you,

Answer (score 2):

You can declare a composite index between `product_id` and `keyword`:

https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb3/Model-definition-JSON-file.html#indexes

```
{
  "name": "comparative",
  "plural": "comparative",
  "base": "PersistedModel",
  "idInjection": true,
  "options": {
     "validateUpsert": true
   },
  "properties": {
    "product_id": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "keyword": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  },
  "validations": [],
  "relations": {},
  "acls": [],
  "methods": {},
  "indexes": {
    "productid_keyword_index": {
      "keys": {
        "product_id": 1, 
        "keyword": -1
      }, 
      "options": {
        "unique": true
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to put `id: true` in the properties. This is done only to a single field, if you don't want the default identification ie. `_id` in mongo

```
"properties": {
    "product_id": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    },
    "keyword": {
      "type": "string",
      "required": true
    }
  }
```

I assume that you have another model Product to which you want relate this model. In order to achieve this, add relations

check [this](https://loopback.io/doc/en/lb2/Creating-model-relations.html) loopback documentation to do so.

Hope this helped